# REACT REDUX component renders infinitely caused by infinitely dispatching action in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Parent component is just a presentation component  it uses UserContent child component, in this child component the redux actions are dispatched and data is rendered:

Parent Component(UserManagement):

```
 <main className={classes.mainContent}>
  <Usercontent />
 </main>
```

Child Component(UserContent):

```
class UserContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: ""
    };
  }
 //The problem is here in componentDidMount()
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll());
  }
 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    if (!this.props.listofusers) {
      return <div>loading..</div>;
    }
    return (

     );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    listofusers: Object.values(state.users)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(UserContent));
```

My Routes in App.js are:

```
 <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/callback" component={Callback} />
              <SecuredRoute
                exact
                path="/dashboard"
                checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}
                component={DashBoard}
              <SecuredRoute
                exact
                path="/users/management"
                checkingSession={this.state.checkingSession}
                component={UserManagement}
              />      
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
```

Comment: Where is your `mapDispatchToProps` function. You cannot get `dispatch` on `props`  without that. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: no i am not getting any error in the console.

Comment: @JayendraSharan, from the react redux: If you don't specify the second argument to connect(), your component will receive dispatch by default.